# Can't install pybind on macOS

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am learning pybind and follwing this tutorial https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing.html

My actions

```
python3.10 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install pybind11
```

Then I am creating example.cpp

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring

    m.def("add", &add, "A function that adds two numbers");
}
```

And trying

```
g++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC $(python3 -m pybind11 --includes) example.cpp -o example$(python3-config --extension-suffix)
```

I had an error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
> "_PyBaseObject_Type", referenced from:
> pybind11::detail::make_object_base_type(_typeobject*) in example-243936.o

Fixed the error with help of **-undefined dynamic_lookup**

```
g++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11  -undefined dynamic_lookup   -fPIC $(python3 -m pybind11 --includes) example.cpp -o example$(python3-config --extension-suffix)
```

Then I received DLL library example.cpython-39-darwin.so
I was trying to use the library

```
# python
Python 3.10.5 (v3.10.5:f377153967, Jun  6 2022, 12:36:10) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pybind11
>>> import example
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example'
>>>
```

How to fix the import error?

Details

```
MacOS version 12.2.1

pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        22.0.4
pybind11   2.10.4
setuptools 58.1.0

Python 3.10.5

g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.27.3)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: You need to link against Python libraries.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What should I change in my actions?

Comment: No idea how it works on mac os but try adding `$(python3-config --embed --ldflags)` to your compilation command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While adding `$(python3-config --embed --ldflags)` as commented might help, providing the linker flags necessary for embedding the Python interpreter (used as `g++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -undefined dynamic_lookup -fPIC $(python3 -m pybind11 --includes) example.cpp -o example$(python3-config --extension-suffix) $(python3-config --embed --ldflags)` ), that would not explain the original error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example'
```

That error should mean the shared library (`example.cpython-39-darwin.so`) isn't in a directory where Python can find it.
When you try to import example, Python looks in several places (like the current directory, and the directories listed in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable) for a file named `example.py` or `example.so`.

So try and add the folder of `example.cpython-39-darwin.so` to your `PYTHONPATH`:

```
export `PYTHONPATH=/path/to/directory:$PYTHONPATH`
```

Comment: @mascai Did the update to `PYTHONPATH` work?

Comment: Yes, this helped ```
PYTHONPATH="/Users/mascai/root_folder/dev/projects/12_pybind:$PYTHONPATH"
export PYTHONPATH ```